# How can I prevent checking checkbox of the record with different cell value of Devexpress gridview?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am working in .NET Web form.
I have a DevExpress gridview in which a gridview data column is a devexpress checkbox.
There is also a column named 'ProductName'. Users will able to check multiple columns but with the same 'ProductName'.

Users are allowed to check any checkboxe first time. After clicking first checkboxes if a user click a check boxes of a record with different productname then an error message should be appeared and checkbox will be unchecked.

After first time clicking all the comparisons  will be done with the productname of the first clicked records.

Client side event is preferable. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy to accomplish with the [ASPxClientGridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridViewtopic) methods. Essentially you would just need to handle the [RowClick Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_RowClicktopic) or [SelectionChanged Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_SelectionChangedtopic) to add some custom logic to compare the newly selected row to already selected.

**Example**

[DevExpress example of how to use checkbox selection](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Selection/Selection.aspx)

Add an event handler to the grid

```
<ClientSideEvents SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged" />
```

Example event handler

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function grid_SelectionChanged(s,e) {
                s.GetSelectedFieldValues("ContactName",GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
            }
            function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values) {
                selList.BeginUpdate();
                try {
                    selList.ClearItems();
                    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
                        selList.AddItem(values[i]);
                    }
                } finally {
                    selList.EndUpdate();
                }
                document.getElementById("selCount").innerHTML=grid.GetSelectedRowCount();
            }
        </script>
```